# getLineCount returns the number of characters after orientation not the lines number

Tags: android, textview, android-viewtreeobserver

I am trying to make an expandable textview, it is working correctly,
 but the problem is after rotation the textview.getLinesCount() returns the number of charcters in the textview not the number of lines, so it doesn't work correctly after the rotation !

here is my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_info, container, false);
    if (getArguments() != null) {

       overView = getArguments().getString("overview");
    }
    overViewTv = view.findViewById(R.id.info_overview);
    moreView = view.findViewById(R.id.overview_more);
    overViewTv.setText(overView);
    int maxLines = 3;
    overViewTv.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreDraw() {
            overViewTv.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
            if (!moreClicked) {
                if (overViewTv.getLineCount() > maxLines) {
                    moreView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    overViewTv.setMaxLines(maxLines);
                    moreClicked = true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });

    moreView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (moreClicked) {
                    moreView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_less_black_24dp);
                    overViewTv.setMaxLines(overViewTv.getLineCount());
                    moreClicked = false;
                } else {
                    moreView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_expand_more_black_24dp);
                    overViewTv.setMaxLines(maxLines);
                    moreClicked = true;
                }
            }
        });

    return view;

}
```

I also tried this method `getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener()` , but same thing happened.

Comment: Where is the code you call `getLinesCount`?

Comment: @BachVu it is in onPreDraw()

Comment: Have you tried `overViewTv.post(new Runnable() {`?

Comment: no, I will give it a try and let you know the result